# intermediate server (opensource) in between legacy wcf web service and mobile app

Tags: wcf, web-services, caching, mobile, web

We have a legacy WCF web service and its front end developed in html. Now we are planning to develop mobile apps or mobile web for commonly used modules. From the mobile app, we are planning to invoke the web services. The web services are developed as ReSTful web services. But the problems with the web services are there is not pagination implemented in any of the web services. So if we are invoking the web services from the mobile app, then it may crash due the heavy data (JSON). For example for customer list web services, it returns all the customer details in a single call. At this point of time the mobile app may be very slow or it may crash.

So that we are planning to develop a proxy in between legacy web services and mobile apps. The mobile apps may invoke the proxy (as restful web services return json) to get the data and the pagination like items we can implement in the proxy. And we need to use Microsoft technologies for this. Our question is, is there any similar projects are available in codeplex or any open sources?

Anybody came across the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the calls is very large (customer list web services) and you want to page it, there is no out of the box software I know of that will do this for you.

Any proxy you introduce will obviously have to make the one big call and then page it for the original client.

But what you might do is introduce an intermediary caching system, store the results from the big WCF calls there, and then write a new service on top of that.

AppFabric is a Microsoft distributed cache that can do this for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric#AppFabric_Caching

So I would write a job to periodically call the WCF service and put those results into AppFabric and then write a new service that reads from AppFabric.

Comment: Thanks alot!!!... I was really struck-up here. From you answer got a light to go through...